# What're the differences between "display", "display-device", "monitor", "screen" in /etc/X11/xorg.conf and the $DISPLAY environment variable?

Tags: xorg, environment-variables, xorg.conf

In the xorg.conf file there are

```
_ Section "Screen"
_ Section "Monitor"
_ Option  "UseDisplayDevice" (inside the screen section)
```

plus the `$DISPLAY` environment variable.

Which one of those 4 (screen, monitor, display-device, $DISPLAY) refers to the physical "screen (or whatever it is)" sitting on my table, and what are the other 3?

Comment: That would be a *monitor* sitting on your table. Some of the other terms are [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Key_terms).

Answer (score 3):

The physical "screen" is "monitor" in Xorg.

If you have multiple monitor, all of the monitor must fit into your current screen. 
For example, I will query my current value with command `xrandr`

```
$ xrandr --query
```

I got the output like

```
Screen 0: ... current 8960 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 5120x2160+3840+0 ... 673mm x 284mm
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 ... 597mm x 336mm
```

screen size `8960` is result of my two monitor resolution `5120+3840`

#### Display

The "display" composed of many screen. Normally we don't have many screen.
You can see your current display by the command `w`

```
USER     TTY    LOGIN@   ...
...      :1     13:52   ...
```

You can see the current display is `:1`. 
Alternatively, you can check it with environment variable.

```
echo $DISPLAY
// :1
```